# VB.NET BindingSource.Filter for multiple variables strange behaviour

Tags: vb.net, filter, datagridview, bindingsource

I have got a `DataGridView` with datasource from MsAccess file which i quickly filter thru the many `TextBox`
If add one more TextBox filtering for a one more column, then filtering is not working properly, for example is showing only 5 results where it should be showing 160 reusults

Working properly:
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaSSj.png)

```
Private Sub MPR_Filtrowanie(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FMPR_data.TextChanged, FMPR_kod.TextChanged, FMPR_opis.TextChanged,
    FMPR_regal.TextChanged, FMPR_uwagi.TextChanged, FMPR_lotto.TextChanged, FMPR_akcja.TextChanged, FMPR_lotto_prod.TextChanged

    MPruchyBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Convert(data,'System.String') like '%{0}' and Convert(KodMP,'System.String') like '%{1}'
    and Convert(opis_gal,'System.String') like '%{2}%' and Convert(regal,'System.String') like '%{3}' and Convert(uwagi,'System.String') like '%{4}%'
    and Convert(lotto,'System.String') like '%{5}%' and Convert(akcja,'System.String') like '%{6}%'",
    _FMPR_data.Text.ToString, FMPR_kod.Text.ToString, FMPR_opis.Text.ToString, FMPR_regal.Text.ToString,
    _FMPR_uwagi.Text.ToString, FMPR_lotto.Text.ToString, FMPR_akcja.Text.ToString)

    MPRdgv.DataSource = MPruchyBindingSource

End sub
```

Not working properly (just one more column): [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQlji.png)

```
Private Sub MPR_Filtrowanie(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FMPR_data.TextChanged, FMPR_kod.TextChanged, FMPR_opis.TextChanged,
    FMPR_regal.TextChanged, FMPR_uwagi.TextChanged, FMPR_lotto.TextChanged, FMPR_akcja.TextChanged, FMPR_lotto_prod.TextChanged

    MPruchyBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Convert(data,'System.String') like '%{0}' and Convert(KodMP,'System.String') like '%{1}'
    and Convert(opis_gal,'System.String') like '%{2}%' and Convert(regal,'System.String') like '%{3}' and Convert(uwagi,'System.String') like '%{4}%'
    and Convert(lotto,'System.String') like '%{5}%' and Convert(akcja,'System.String') like '%{6}%' and Convert(lotto_prod,'System.String') like '%{7}%'",
    _FMPR_data.Text.ToString, FMPR_kod.Text.ToString, FMPR_opis.Text.ToString, FMPR_regal.Text.ToString,
    _FMPR_uwagi.Text.ToString, FMPR_lotto.Text.ToString, FMPR_akcja.Text.ToString, FMPR_lotto_prod.Text.ToString)

    MPRdgv.DataSource = MPruchyBindingSource

End sub
```

Comment: Firstly, get rid of all those `ToString` calls. the `Text` of a control is type `String`, so calling `ToString` on it is pointless. Even if it was another type though, `String.Format` will call `ToString` implicitly.

Comment: As for the issue, it looks like it is filtering out all the records that are empty in that column. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I wonder whether those empty columns are actually null and your filter is not matching for that reason, where it would match an empty string. That seems the most likely explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that the issue is that your filter will match only string values and not nulls so your filter is excluding rows where that column is null. In that case, you can change this:

```sql
    Convert(lotto_prod,'System.String') like '%{7}%'
```

to this:

```sql
    CONVERT(ISNULL(lotto_prod, ''),'System.String') LIKE '%{7}%'
```

and I think it should work. You may need to do similarly for other columns that could contain nulls.

Comment: thanks! it worked. Is it possible to avoid this next time for example during database or dataset design?

Comment: So i found out this behaviour, if i assign empty textbox (Nothing) to the datatable column value then filtering is working (i guess no DBnull anymore) but if the datatable column was never touched then there are DBnulls?

Comment: @Mateusz, you shouldn't be basing your database design on this. Your database design should be based on the data and then you build your app to work with that design. If it makes sense that your columns contain no data then they should be nullable and not if it doesn't. If your column is nullable then you shouldn't be saving an empty string when it should actually be null. Don't make your data garbage because it's too much trouble to write proper code.